# Algorithm for cropping an image without removing a specified part of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, crop, cgrect

I'm hoping writing this out may help with my issue. I have images that contain faces, and I want to recrop these images, respecting aspect ratio, while maintaining as much of the face as possible.

I want to crop the image to an arbitrary rectangle, which could be tall, short, square, or anything up to 4:1 aspect. As much as possible, I want to avoid cropping out a face or feature that I've specified (as an interior rectangle to the image's rect). E.G. I have an image rectangle of (0,0,500, 300) and a feature rectangle of (20, 40, 75, 75), and I want to crop it (respecting its aspect ratio) to a rectangle of (0,0, 320,200), all while minimally cropping the face rectangle.

I have a working implementation for center cropping, where I determine the larger side of the image and scale the other side based on the same ratio, setting x and y to the center of scaled w/h - target w/h.

For clarity, the signature would look something like this (in Obj-C):

```
(CGRect)crop:(CGSize)sourceSize toFitSize:(CGSize)fitSize withoutCroppingRect:(CGRect)featuresRect
```

Where `sourceSize` is the original image's size, `fitSize` is the shape I want to crop the image into, and `featuresRect` is a rectangle, within the bounds of `(0,0,sourceSize.width, sourceSize,height)`.

Perhaps this should be done as a "center crop", centered on the feature rectangle? Trying to wrap my head around what this would even mean.

Comment: You cannot crop an image rectangle (0,0,500, 300) to (0,0, 300,200) while preserving the aspect ratio, because 500/300 != 300/200. - And what should happen if the "feature rectangle" does not fit into the destination rectangle?

Comment: @MartinR Good point, I had just typed that up quickly. I suppose the algorithm does not HAVE to respect the feature rectangle completely, but would need to do the best job it could. That's part of the issue ;)

Comment: Maybe if you told us what you're actually trying to accomplish instead of how you've tried to accomplish it, we could suggest something. Right now, everything you've written is so vague that there could probably be an infinite number of answers. If the "feature rectangle" generally contains a face, it might be useful to have the center of the feature rectangle fall on one of the [1/3rd lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thirds) in the image to produce a generally pleasing result. Or if you prefer, on one of the [golden ratio lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Aesthetics)

Comment: @user1118321 I've just updated to hopefully help explain what I am trying to do. I've had good results just center cropping. Perhaps what I want is to center crop based on the feature rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this, I think it does what you want, or at least it nudges you in the right direction. The output rect keeps the same aspect ratio as the source image rect.

Example usage:

```
 CGRect sizedRect = [self cropSize:self.inputView.image.size
                         toFitSize:self.outputView.bounds.size
               withoutCroppingRect:self.regionOfInterest.frame];

 CGImageRef cgImage = self.inputView.image.CGImage;

 CGImageRef cgCroppedImage =  CGImageCreateWithImageInRect (
                                         cgImage,
                                         sizedRect
                                         );

 self.outputView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgCroppedImage];
```

There are a number of issues that you are going to have to consider, in particular:
- Your returned rect may be larger than the fitSize, as it will not crop the featuresRect, so you may have to check for this and scale the image after applying the crop (or set your output imageView's scaleToFit appropriately).
- where are you getting your ROI frame data from? Is it relative to the original source image, or to the imageView containing the source image. If it is the latter you will need to ensure your source image is sized 1:1 with it's imageView, as the crop rect is applied to the image, not it's imageView.
- the output imageView is smaller than the input imageView. I am not sure what this does if it is larger, but it  may introduce similar scaling issues.
- you will need to add divide-by-zero error checking.

```
-     (CGRect)cropSize:(CGSize)sourceSize 
             toFitSize:(CGSize)fitSize
   withoutCroppingRect:(CGRect)featuresRect
{
    CGRect result = CGRectZero;
    BOOL fitSizeIsTaller;
    CGFloat sourceRatio = sourceSize.width / sourceSize.height;
    CGFloat fitRatio    = fitSize.width    / fitSize.height;
     if (sourceRatio > fitRatio)
            fitSizeIsTaller = YES;
     else   fitSizeIsTaller = NO;

        //size sourceRect to fitSize
    if (fitSizeIsTaller){
        result.size.width  = fitSize.width;
        result.size.height = result.size.width / sourceRatio;
    } else {
        result.size.height = fitSize.height;
        result.size.width  = result.size.height * sourceRatio;
    }
        //make sure it is at least as large as fitSize
    if (result.size.height < featuresRect.size.height) {
        result.size.height = featuresRect.size.height;
        result.size.width  = result.size.height * sourceRatio;
    }

    if (result.size.width  < featuresRect.size.width) {
        result.size.width  = featuresRect.size.width;
        result.size.height = result.size.width / sourceRatio;
    }

            //locate resultRect in center
    result.origin.x = (sourceSize.width  - result.size.width )/2;
    result.origin.y = (sourceSize.height - result.size.height)/2;

            //shift origin of result to make sure it includes ROI

    if (featuresRect.origin.x < result.origin.x )    //shift right?
              result.origin.x = featuresRect.origin.x;
    else
        if ((featuresRect.origin.x + featuresRect.size.width)  
               >  (result.origin.x + result.size.width))  //shift left?
            result.origin.x = (featuresRect.origin.x + featuresRect.size.width)
                            - result.size.width;

    if (featuresRect.origin.y < result.origin.y )    //shift up?
              result.origin.y = featuresRect.origin.y;
    else
        if ((featuresRect.origin.y + featuresRect.size.height)  
                > (result.origin.y + result.size.height))  //shift down?
            result.origin.y = (featuresRect.origin.y+featuresRect.size.height)
                            - result.size.height;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The ROI is relative to the actual image. Just using face detection for the region, for now. I'll check this out--I'm sure it will at least point me in the right direction.